# Inheritance of Delegate

Tags: inheritance, qooxdoo

I created a Class with a Selectbox and some Listitems. To change the Label of these Items I set the Delegate of the selectbox controller with a `configureItem`.

Know I want to add some Child Elements of these class and add some Items to the list. Now I have to adjust the `configureItem` by calling a function in the configureItem. This Function checks if the Item is in the current class, when it is not I call the superclass method who handles the label of his Items.

This worked well is Qooxdoo 5.0.2. Now I changed to Qooxdoo 6 to use the new compiler and I get the Error: `Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them` when calling the Superclass Method.

Here are some Code snippets:

```js
//Set Delegate in superclass
this.operatorController.setDelegate({
    configureItem : function(item) {
        that.operatorDelegateItems(item, that);
    }
});

// Superclass Method
operatorDelegateItems : function(item, that) {
        switch (item.getLabel()) {
        case "":
            item.setLabel(qx.locale.Manager.tr("Ist Vorhanden"));
            break;
        case "-":
            item.setLabel(qx.locale.Manager.tr("Ist nicht Vorhanden"));
            break;
        case "Nachfolger":
            item.setLabel(qx.locale.Manager.tr("Zeige Nachfolger"));
            break;
        }
    }

// Child class Delegate FUnction
operatorDelegateItems : function(item, that) {
    if (item.getLabel() == "Period")
        item.setLabel("Jahresintervall");
    else
        that.base(arguments, item);
}
```

Someone can help me with this or is there a better approach to solve my problem?

Comment: The error refers to the fact that `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee` are not available in strict mode (which Qooxdoo 6 applications use), your snippet does not use that so I need more information.  Please can you provide a working example in the playground (http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler only supports `this.base` and you've aliased `this` as `that` and so it's not recognised.

I've added this as an issue here (https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-compiler/issues/102) and that specific problem needs to be fixed before we release 6.0.

Looking at your code, the fix is that carrying around `this` in the `that` variable is not necessary, so changing your code to `this.base` works (thanks for trying that out on [Gitter qooxdoo](https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo)!)

However, if you weren't able to just change to using `this.base`, the work around is to use explicit method calls, eg instead of `that.base` you'd use something like

```
operatorDelegateItems : function(item, that) {
    if (item.getLabel() == "Period")
        item.setLabel("Jahresintervall");
    else
        myapp.MyBaseClass.prototype.operatorDelegateItems.call(this, item, that);
}
```